# get result with "evaluation" from join statement in java

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to get result from 3 inner join in java code with sql.

I tried this

```
BeanHandler rsh=new BeanHandler(evaluation.class);
          evaluation eval=(evaluation) runner.query(query,new Object[]{userid}, rsh);
```

This code return the result from query, but with "join" statement it's not working, I want to get result from 3 tables.

any ideas?

Edit: (the query)

```
String query=" select users.username, sum(evaluation.mark)\n" +
                    "from  users inner JOIN user_has_eval \n" +
                    "on users.id= user_has_eval.user_id inner JOIN\n" +
                    "evaluation ON evaluation.id=user_has_eval.eval_id\n" +
                    "where evaluation.types=\"Secretaria\" and users.id = ? \n" +
                    "\n" ;
```

Comment: too few details to understand the problem. please add the query, the Evaluation class, etc.

Comment: @SourabhMahajan edited, thanks alot